# PHP validating radio button/survey answers have been selected

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and struggling through this assignment.   I posted a similar question earlier but I left out part of my code.  I've worked on it a bit more and still not getting it to work. After the user selects a survey, they are given a sequence of 10 questions. They must select an answer (radio button) and then click submit which takes them to the next question.  Right now, the user can go through all the questions, clicking submit after each one, without selecting an answer. I know I need to validate that an answer (radio button) has been chosen for each question. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've read dozens of articles that explain validation but there are so many parts to this assignment. I have no clue where to even include my validation. Help would be appreciated. I understand that I'm only suppose to include the relevant attempted code but I am uncertain, right now, what parts of my code are essential to present my problem.  I apologize if I include too much.

```html
$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submitButton') !== NULL;
if ($isPostBack) {
    // This is what happens if there is a postback.
    $choose_survey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choose_survey', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);



    if ($choose_survey !== NULL) {
        // Check the value of $choose_survey and then set 'survey' accordingly, e.g.
        if ($choose_survey == 0)
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;
        else if ($choose_survey == 1)
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey1;
        else if ($choose_survey == 2)
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey2;
        // A survey is selected so this is what happens.
        // these are the survey questions
       /* $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;*/
        // this will contain the answers
        $_SESSION['answers'] = array();
        // this is the question number
        $_SESSION['number'] = 1;
    } else {
        // A survey is not selected because it was already chosen.
        // get the value from the radio button.
        $answer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'answer', FILTER_DEFAULT);
        if ($answer !== NULL) {
           $_SESSION['answers'] = $answer;
        } else if ($answer == NULL) {
            echo '<p>Please selection an answer</p>';
        }

        // Stop user from submitting survey question that hasn't been answered


        $question_key = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'question_key', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        // this will be used later to display the answers/results
        $_SESSION['answers'][$question_key] = $answer;
        // This is adding 1 to the question number.
        $_SESSION['number'] += 1;
        unset($_SESSION['survey'][$question_key]);
    }
} else 
   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" action="survey.php">
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['survey'])):
        echo '<p>Please choose a survey</p>';

        foreach ($surveys as $key => $value) {
            $surveyButton = <<<HEREDOC
    <label for = "$key">$value</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choose_survey" id="$key" value="$key"><br>
HEREDOC;
            echo $surveyButton;
        }
    else: ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <p class="survey-header">Please respond to each survey statement</p>
            <?php
            $key = array_key_first($_SESSION['survey']);
            $value = $_SESSION['survey'][$key];
            $surveyQuestions = <<<HEREDOC
            <input type="hidden" name="question_key" value="$key">
    <label class="statement"> $value </label>
        <ul class='likert'>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="strong_agree">
                <label>Strongly agree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="agree">
                <label>Agree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="neutral">
                <label>Neutral</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="disagree">
                <label>Disagree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="strong_disagree">
                <label>Strongly disagree</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
HEREDOC;

            echo $surveyQuestions;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to validate it on the server, correct.  No Javascript for example?  Can you post an example of `$choose_survey` value.  For example after `filter_input` do `var_export($choose_survey)` and add the results (or output of that) to the question.  As the answer depends on how your data is structured.

Comment: Your use of HEREDOC might lose some marks, as its only making it harder to read your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this harder then it has to be.

```
 $answer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'answer', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    if ($answer !== NULL) {
       $_SESSION['answers'] = $answer;
    } else if ($answer == NULL) {
        echo '<p>Please selection an answer</p>';
    }

    // Stop user from submitting survey question that hasn't been answered


    $question_key = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'question_key', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
   // this will be used later to display the answers/results
   $_SESSION['answers'][$question_key] = $answer;
   // This is adding 1 to the question number.
   $_SESSION['number'] += 1;
   unset($_SESSION['survey'][$question_key]);
```

Replace that with

```
    $answer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'answer', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    if (!$answer) { //because your answers are truthy, no empty values like '0' 
       echo '<p>Please selection an answer</p>';
    }else{
       $_SESSION['answers'] = $answer;
       $question_key = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'question_key', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
       // this will be used later to display the answers/results
       $_SESSION['answers'][$question_key] = $answer;
       // This is adding 1 to the question number.
       $_SESSION['number'] += 1;
       unset($_SESSION['survey'][$question_key]);
    }
```

You already know if it was answered or not, you just didnt structure your code correctly.  In your code it just continues after the condition, in mine it only does the code if `$answer` i not null.

Comment: This is working for me.  Thank you so much.  I understand now what I was doing wrong.  I knew it would be some silly mistake.   However, when I click submit, I am getting a notice "String offset cast occurred on line 64".  Line 64 includes this code: $_SESSION['answers'][$question_key] = $answer;      Do you know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: I did some research and figured out what I needed to do to fix it.  I had to change Filter_Validate_Float to Filter_Validate_Int. Thank you again for your help tonight. I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Kool, I was occupied for a bit there.